# Room Data Fail To Persist When Destroyed or Backpressed and Get Back in The Activity

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-room

I have followed the guideline for app architecture. It said to persist data better use `ROOM`. But when I try it using [this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#4)

That uses the following code :-

```
@Dao
public interface WordDao {

   // allowing the insert of the same word multiple times by passing a 
   // conflict resolution strategy
   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
   void insert(Word word);

   @Query("DELETE FROM word_table")
   void deleteAll();

   @Query("SELECT * from word_table ORDER BY word ASC")
   List<Word> getAlphabetizedWords();
}
```

it fails to persist the data when going back to activity after user back press or destroyed the activity.

Can someone tell me what is the problem or what is my fault?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: the code is in the codelab. that is the official code from google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I already solved this problem. When you insert a new same word, the data still persists. But when you back press or destroyed the data is lost. This example is not valid.

For those are depending on codelab better you find the example in android fundamental and find the room word with update example project. That is the complete and better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all else is working, then the most likely issue is that you are inserting the same word.

The comment appears to be incorrect/misleading, and could easily be interpreted as meaning that the same Word cam be added multiple times. I think what it is meant to be saying is ***allow the insert of an existing/duplicate word to not fail***

However, point **5** is correct it is :-

> **onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE:**
>
> The selected on conflict strategy ignores a new word if it's exactly the same as one already in the list.
>
> To know more about the available conflict strategies, checkout the documentation.